# Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found - Libraries in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I added an external library "FloatingActionButton-master" that I downloaded from https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton but when I sync with the gradle I get this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI1ZP.png)

(I don't have enough reputation to poste the image)
I tried many differents answers from this forum but nothing was helpful for my case. I don't know what is the problem.

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':librerias:FloatingActionButton-master'
```

app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ezequiel.memories"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.31.08"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile project(':librerias:FloatingActionButton-master')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To include that library you don't need to clone/download the repository nor add the source manually, you should only add the dependency as follows:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
}
```

However, according to the library, you should not use it anymore because it is deprecated as the Android supporting library already comes with the FAB (FloatingActionButton) button.

To use the button from the supporting library, you should instead add the following:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
}
```

And then use it in your layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />
```

You can see the following [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/material-design-style/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#6) for more details.

Comment: That sound good. I will try with that and if I have a problem I will be back. Thanks!

Comment: Well...I'm back with this problem trying to use the support library:  Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
               Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

Comment: @EzequielAllio You are using support libraries v24. Use compileSdkVersion 24

Comment: @fernandospr finally I could use _compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'_ so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are declaring:

```
include ':librerias:FloatingActionButton-master'
```

Gradle is going to search in this folder a `build.gradle` file.
In this folder there is a **top-level** `build.gradle` file without a module configuration.
It is the reason of:

> Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

You should use:

```
include ':librerias:FloatingActionButton-master:library'
```

or just copy only the library folder and use:

```
include ':librerias:library'
```

Otherwise check the  @fernandospr's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
```

to

```
compileSdkVersion 24
```

to avoid Android Support libraries problems

then change your dependencies to:

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     compile project(':librerias:FloatingActionButton-master')
     compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
}
```

Remove:

```
include ':librerias:FloatingActionButton-master'
```

and

```
compile project(':librerias:FloatingActionButton-master')
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I put `compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'` and I could create the FAB without use the external library. Thank you very much to all!!